# AndroidX migration using Jetifier tool converts support libraries to RC versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack, androidx, android-jetifier

In the process of migrating to Android X, tt seems that Jetifier tool converts some of the 3rd party libraries to RC versions (gradle-4.6).

```
 |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.34.0
|    |    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.34.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc01
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0-rc01
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0-rc01
|    |    |         +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0
|    |    |         +--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |         +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |         \--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
```

Is there a solution I can force to take only stable (fixed) versions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, after digging in jetifier source code, it seems that the jetifier version comes with gradle-4.6 is alpha10:

/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-alpha10⁩/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-alpha10.jar
/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-alpha10⁩/jetifier-core-1.0.0-alpha10.jar

The local mapping file in this package jetifier converts some of the support libraries to RC versions.

Adding an updated jetifier dependencies solves this issue (top build.gradle):

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta02'
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta02'
```

And here are the results for facebook dependencies tree:

```
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.34.0
|    |    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.34.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0
|    |    |         +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0
|    |    |         +--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |         +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |         \--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 (*)
```

Comment: You have a missed `-` in `jetifier-processor:1.0.0beta02` → should be `1.0.0-beta02` :)